# How to use XMLReader to parse XML document?

Tags: c#, parsing, xmlreader

Here is my XML:

http://simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/OrgTypes/

I want to be able to grab those keyboards under "Type" and ignore the numbers.

Such as Physician, Ambulance, etc.

```
<data>
<row>
<typeId>0</typeId>
<type>Physician</type>
</row>
<row>
<typeId>1</typeId>
<type>Ambulance</type>
</row>
<row>
<typeId>2</typeId>
<type>Fire Department</type>
</row>
<row>
<typeId>3</typeId>
<type>Helicopter/Air Transport</type>
</row>
</data>
```

How would I do that in C#?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Show what have you tried already, there is a lot about parsing XML in C#.

Comment: I would cheat, create a System.Data.DataTable object in memory, use the DataTable.ReadXML function, and have it in a nice handy DataTable to work with.  But that's a hack, and I'd probably be shot if I put that as a real answer.

Comment: And ...I recommend learning LINQ-to-XML (XDocument) from the get-go.

Comment: @DavidStratton: it's not a hack if the Xml is from a serialized DataTable (which it could be).

Comment: My bad. I mean Visual C#.

Comment: have you tried googling, sir? If you know XMLReader you might now where to find the documentation for it as well, I suppose. Nonetheless, google for XDocument examples too

Answer (score 4):

```
var types = XDocument.Load("http://simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/OrgTypes/")
                .Descendants("type")
                .Select(t => (string)t)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: The values are always `string` coming from Xml document.

Comment: @IAbstract and what? I don't understand your comment. Above code returns 14 items as `List<string>`

Comment: I'm saying the cast `(string)` should be unnecessary. :) ... but I'd also recommend being explicit (since our OP is new to C#) and include `t.Value`.

Comment: @IAbstract no it is not unnecessary. It is the same as `t.Value` (t is XElement)

Comment: `t.Value` cannot result in a null value because Value will return an empty string. I removed a value in the node and used `t.Value` -- no crash, no null exception ... simply a blank line.

Comment: @IAbstract It is just to be safe. try this code `string xml = "<a><b>no c in this xml</b></a>";
    var types = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                    .Descendants("a")
                    .Select(t => t.Element("c").Value)
                    .ToList();` also with casting. I don't understand why did you get so irritated about a simple detail.

Comment: Since when does a ' :) ' at the end of a comment mean I am irritated? Certainly not. I am pointing out some basic things that I would expect to be taught properly to a beginner. **:)**

Comment: And I believe your example will return an exception but not in the same manner as you believe you are avoiding in your answer

Comment: @IAbstract `Believe` doesn't mean much.To help to OP as you said, It must be more clear.  Yes or No. (BTW: have you tried it?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42897/discussion-between-iabstract-and-l-b)

Comment: I must be very popular today :) Another chat invitation. No thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This method is really incomplete and deserves some explanation for a beginner to C# and LINQ-to-XML:

```
var types = XDocument.Load("http://simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/OrgTypes/")
                .Descendants("type")
                .Select(t => (string)t) // under the hood magic
                .ToList();
```

The use of `(string)` to cast is a little magical and doesn't get the same results if `ToString()` were used. I'll explain ... I modified the XML just a little:

```
<type attrib="bar" attrib2="boo" >Resource
    <foo a="1" a.2="A"/>
</type>
// note, I also removed the value of type immediately following Resource node
```

The `(string)` cast on `t` is acting on the `t.Value` under the hood. Without the cast, the result is:

```
<type>Physician</type>  
<type>Ambulance</type>  
<type>Fire Department</type>  
<type>Helicopter/Air Transport</type>  
<type>Home Care Agency</type>  
<type>Hospital</type>  
<type>Law Enforcement Agency</type>  
<type>Nursing Home</type>
<type attrib="bar" attrib2="boo">Resource  
                <foo a="1" a.2="A" /></type>  
<type></type>  
<type>Other</type>  
<type>Hospice</type>  
<type>School</type>  
<type>Emergency Shelter</type>
```

Using `(string)t`:

```
Physician
Ambulance
Fire Department
Helicopter/Air Transport
Home Care Agency
Hospital
Law Enforcement Agency
Nursing Home
Resource


Other
Hospice
School
Emergency Shelter
```

And `t.Value`:

```
Physician
Ambulance
Fire Department
Helicopter/Air Transport
Home Care Agency
Hospital
Law Enforcement Agency
Nursing Home
Resource


Other
Hospice
School
Emergency Shelter
```

And lastly, to show that `t.ToString()` is different than `(string)t`:

```
<type>Physician</type>
<type>Ambulance</type>
<type>Fire Department</type>
<type>Helicopter/Air Transport</type>
<type>Home Care Agency</type>
<type>Hospital</type>
<type>Law Enforcement Agency</type>
<type>Nursing Home</type>
<type attrib="bar" attrib2="boo">Resource
                <foo a="1" a.2="A" /></type>
<type></type>
<type>Other</type>
<type>Hospice</type>
<type>School</type>
<type>Emergency Shelter</type>
```

All of this to reiterate some little-known *issues* with LINQ-to-XML.

My recommendation for clarity and ease of maintenance would be as follows:

```
var types = XDocument.Load("http://simon.ist.rit.edu:8080/Services/resources/ESD/OrgTypes/")
                .Descendants("type")
                .Select(t => t.Value) // be explicit about what you want
                .ToList();
```

You can search for any [element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.extensions.elements%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [descendant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.extensions.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `IEnumerable` flavor.

Comment: Nice if the question were *what does `.Select(t => (string)t)`* mean

Comment: Yes ... **and** it answers the OP's question while explaining why another answer is implicit and bad coding form. We are supposed to offer complete answers and to a new C# user, I expect a higher level of participation.

Comment: `it answers the OP's question while explaining ....` But by copying the whole logic from other answer.... So explanation of someone else's answer doesn't make this an answer.

Comment: I added my own answer and why I recommend it over another. And because I did so in this manner, I made this post CW so as not to glean any rep.